# How to remove "Microsoft' was used before it was defined" jslint error

Tags: bing-maps, jslint

Error:

> Microsoft' was used before it was defined.

I am using bing MAP API to implement the bing map in my webpage.

```
var map;
function getMap() {
  map = new Microsoft.Maps.Map(document.getElementById('myMap'), {credentials: 'bing map key'});
}
```

How do I use function in js file without a jslint error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Exclude the Microsoft object from JSLint's inspection.

```
/*global Microsoft: false */
```

http://www.jslint.com/lint.html